# Hide new command contents

Tags: macros

I am adding comments to my latex using newly defined commands like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\mycomment}[3]{\textcolor{#1}{\small [#2: #3]}}
\newcommand{\reviewerA}[1]{\mycomment{blue}{Reviewer 1:}{#1}}
%...
\reviewerA{bla bla}
```

is there a single command that I can use to hide all contents in the comments?

Comment: Do you want to remove all `\mycomment` from the document using another command?

Comment: its fine to have them in the latex file, just not in the output pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to toggle all the comment on and off in the output PDF, you can simply redefine the commands to be blank

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[3]{\textcolor{#1}{\small [#2: #3]}}
\newcommand{\reviewerA}[1]{\mycomment{blue}{Reviewer 1:}{#1}}
%...
\newcommand{\mycomment}[3]{}
\newcommand{\reviewerA}[1]{}
%...
\reviewerA{bla bla}
```

And if you want to get back the commands, you'll need to remove or just comment those blank variants.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newif\ifprintcomments
\newcommand{\mycomment}[3]{%
  \ifprintcomments
    \hfill % I added this, you can skip it if you want.
    \textcolor{#1}{\small [#2: #3]}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\reviewerA}[1]{%
  \ifprintcomments
    \mycomment{blue}{Reviewer 1}{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\printcommentstrue

Hey I think $1+1=3$\reviewerA{This is bullshit!}

and $2+2=6$\reviewerA{Bruh! :/}

\printcommentsfalse

Hey I think $1+1=3$\reviewerA{This is bullshit!}

and $2+2=6$\reviewerA{Bruh! :/}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

---

### Explanation

What I basically do here is; I define a conditional with `\newif\ifprintcomments` and add your definition only when this conditional is true, i.e., when `\printcommentstrue`. As soon as you issue `\printcommentsfalse` the meaning is lost. Hence you output nothing. Cheers!

---

Note: I added an `\hfill`. If you don't like it, please remove it. Also I removed the `:` from the definition of `\reviewerA` as it was printing it twice. Notice that you have one `:` in the definition of `\mycomment` also.